# JavaScript for Formatted Last Day of Month

Tags: javascript, date

I can show the last day of whatever the current month is or I can show the current date formatted the way I want, but not both. For example, in February I want the script to generate 2/28/2017; in March it would generate 3/31/2017; April 4/30/2017; etc.

```js
function ShowDate0() {
  var date = new Date(),
    y = date.getFullYear(),
    m = date.getMonth();
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
  document.getElementById("showdate0").innerHTML = lastDay;
}

function ShowDate1() {
  var date = new Date(),
         y = date.getFullYear(),
         m = date.getMonth();
  var lastDay = date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("showdate1").innerHTML = lastDay;
}
window.onload = function(){
  ShowDate0();
  ShowDate1();
}
```

```html
<b>Last Day with verbose formatting (Day-of-week Month Day Year Time GMT-Time Time Zone):</b>
<p id="showdate0"></p>

<b> Current date with desired formatting(m / d / yyyy): </b>
<p id="showdate1"></p>
```

I therefore thought this would work to display the last day of the month with m/d/yyyy formatting, but the month is behind (displaying 1/28/2017 when it should be 2/28/2017):

```js
function ShowDate() {
  var date = new Date(),
    y = date.getFullYear(),
    m = date.getMonth();
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
  var formatted = lastDay.getMonth() + "/" + lastDay.getDate() + "/" + lastDay.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("showdate").innerHTML = formatted;
}
window.onload = ShowDate;
```

```html
<p id="showdate"></p>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: In both cases you need to add one to the month for display, so `lastDay.getMonth() + 1`.

Comment: `getMonth()` reports a range from `0-11` with `0` as Jan and `11` as Dec.

Comment: Thanks, @RobG, that fixed it.  And it seems like an obvious fix, but I'm still not sure why it's needed because I thought that's what I was doing with the m + 1 on the line above it.

Comment: The `m + 1` sets it to the following month, but setting the day to `0` sets it back to the last day of the original month. So if it's February, then *getMonth* returns 1. Setting it to `2, 0` sets it to 28 Feb (in a non-leap year), so *getMonth* still returns 1. ;-)

Comment: That's part of my confusion, because setting it to (y, m + 2, 0), (y, m + 3, 0), etc. didn't do anything for the month; it just changed the number of days in the month.  I would have expected it to bump the month forward and, unless I'm misunderstanding you, that's what you seem to be suggesting as well.  I could see the month variable being reset back to zero if I'm calling getMonth again, so there's probably just a cleaner way to write it so I don't have to duplicate the m + 1.